# is there anything that can preload ads anchor banner ads specially?

Tags: java, android, ads

i am working on android ads integration and stuck in one logical side where i have to load anchor banner ads of Admob but if it's not visible i want to load google or facebook ads instead of it can you please help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share some code and an example of your desired output.